# Excel vba - Custom workday function throws error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am unable to fix the type mismatch error in the VBA function, can anyone assist?

```
sub test()
MsgBox NSEBDay(Date)
Endsub

Function NSEBDay(InPut_Date As Date) As Boolean
Dim MyDate As Date
Dim Hday As Range
Set Hday = wksBackup.Range("TSys_NSEHoliday")

MyDate = Application.Evaluate("=workday(InPut_Date+1,-1," & Hday.Address(0, 0) & ")")

If InPut_Date = MyDate Then
    NSEBDay = MyDate
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little more straight forward. Tested and working fine on my end.

```
MyDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(InPut_Date + 1, -1, Hday)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the Endsub to End Sub in the first function.  I'm guessing that's just a typo.

On the expression in function 2, please make the following change:

```
MyDate = Application.Evaluate("=workday(""" & DateAdd("d", InPut_Date, 1) & """,-1," & Hday.Address(0, 0) & ")")
```

This way, input date is recognized as a variable rather than part of a string.  The DateAdd function adds a single day to the value.